# Random string generating function

Tags: python, performance, random

Both these functions take in a sentence and generate a random string based of the length of `sentence`.

Mine, the first one, runs 4 times more slowly than the second one (someone else's code), but I don't know why and I'd like to understand what's happening 'under the hood' that makes it this way. If anything I would've expected numpy to be faster, which makes me think it's something else entirely.

Also, is there a way to make the first function even faster?

```
import random
import numpy as np

def generate_guess(sentence):   
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ']
    return [np.random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(len(sentence))]
```

**Don't review this one:**

> ```
> def generate_guess(sentence): 
>   alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
>   res = ''
>   for i in range(len(sentence)):
>       res = res + alphabet[random.randrange(len(alphabet))]
>   return res
> ```

Comment: Did you get permission from the owner of the "second" code to make it publicly available and to licence it under CC-BY-SA?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, I did not, I have no idea what CC-BY-SA is but I'll look it up. It's from an online textbook that the author makes completely freely publicly available, so I thought it would be fine. But as I said I'll look into what you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice) takes an additional argument specifying how many elements should be chosen. You can also use the built-in module `string` to save having to spell out the alphabet:

```
import numpy as np
import string

ALPHABET = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase + ' '))


def generate_guess(sentence):
    return np.random.choice(ALPHABET, size=len(sentence))
```

I also made the alphabet a constant to avoid having to build it again and again.

Your code was not faster because you did not take advantage of the vector-wise operations of `numpy`. Neither your starting array, the alphabet, nor your output array were actual numpy arrays.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, and having the alphabet constant is a great point.