# Simple Python code that makes a random string of letters and numbers

Tags: python, random

My code basically picks random letters and numbers from three lists and makes a random combination with them. I decided to write this code just for fun, however I feel like the code can be made shorter. I just don't know how.

So here is my code:

```
import random

caps=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
numbers=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
letters=['a','b','c','d','e','f','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']



for j in range (4):
  lengthcaps=len(caps)
  indexcaps=random.randint(0, lengthcaps)
  fillcaps=caps[indexcaps-1]

  lengthnumbers=len(numbers)
  indexnumbers=random.randint(0, lengthnumbers)
  fillnumber=numbers[indexnumbers-1]

  lengthletters=len(letters)
  indexletters=random.randint(0, lengthletters)
  fillletter=letters[indexletters-1]
  
  list=[fillletter,fillcaps,fillnumber]
  index1list=random.randint(0,2)
  index2list=random.randint(0,2)
  index3list=random.randint(0,2)
  index4list=random.randint(0,2)
  index5list=random.randint(0,2)
  index6list=random.randint(0,2)
  
  fill1list=list[index1list]
  fill2list=list[index2list]
  fill3list=list[index3list]
  fill4list=list[index4list]
  fill5list=list[index5list]
  fill6list=list[index6list]
  
  print(fill1list + fill2list + fill3list + fill4list + fill5list + fill6list)
```

If this is duplicate, please feel free to tell me, because searching for things isn't one of my qualities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random string generating function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151284/random-string-generating-function)

Comment: (I value clout in finding solutions/answers higher than knowing them. *Developing* / *deriving* original ones (if not necessarily new) is something to practice where finding pre-existing ones doesn't succeed or using them is no option.)

Comment: You describe what your code does. Make it a habit to [document the purpose of (parts of) your code](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-docstrings).

Comment: @alexyorke Since we review code here to help the Original Poster to improve their code skills, duplicate questions don't have the same meaning they have on Stack Overflow. Duplicate questions are exact duplicates by the same author.

Comment: if someone wants to generate passwords with this or similar code: in this case you should use the `secrets` module instead of `random`

Comment: @Aemyl, what is the difference between the `secrets` and the `random` module?

Comment: @Jéa the `secrets` module provides a cryptographically strong source of randomness, meaning that even if you know the last x output values of the random number generator, it is practically impossible to compute its internal state, so the next output is always unpredictable. That's not the case for the `random` module, which is the reason why it shouldn't be used for security purposes

Comment: @Aemyl alright thank you! I wasn't going to use this for creating passwords. But this is certainly some good information to know.

Comment: I just realized that your code probably* contains a bug: `random.randint(0, length...)` can return 0, so e.g. `caps[indexcaps-1]` could evaluate to `caps[-1]`, which does not raise an `IndexError`, so it goes unnoticed and makes the selection of `'Z'` twice as likely as the other letters (same for `'z'` and `'0'`). This is another good reason for using `random.choice` instead of `random.randint`. * unless this is intentional behavior

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use `caps`, `numbers` and `letters`; those are all constants available from the `string` module.

Don't assign `j` since it isn't used; name the iteration variable `_` instead.

Replace your length / index / slice with a `random.choices`.

Don't call a variable `list`, since 1. it shadows an existing type called `list`, and 2. it isn't very descriptive.

Rather than your manual, unrolled string appending, just use `''.join()`.

A strictly equivalent implementation could be

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

for _ in range(4):
    fill_caps = random.choice(ascii_uppercase)
    fill_number = random.choice(digits)
    fill_letter = random.choice(ascii_lowercase)
    choices = (fill_letter, fill_caps, fill_number)
    word = ''.join(random.choices(choices, k=6))
    print(word)
```

but your algorithm has some odd properties that, according to your comments, you did not intend. The output word will have the choice of only one lower-case letter, one upper-case letter and one digit. The simpler and less surprising thing to do is generate a word from *any* of those characters:

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

choices = ascii_lowercase + ascii_uppercase + digits

for _ in range(4):
    word = ''.join(random.choices(choices, k=6))
    print(word)
```

Comment: You could use `''.join(random.choices(choices, k=6))` toget rid of the list comprehension (and avoid a few slow attribute lookups).

Comment: The second one was indeed what I was going for, do you have something where I can learn more about `' '.join()`?  Is there a specific reason why I should make `_` instead of `j`? because I just used `j` because I picked a random letter to put there.

Comment: Note that collecting all possible characters together and then choosing characters from the resulting list, `choices = ascii_letters + ascii_uppercase + digits`, has the consequence that each character in the resulting string only has probability 10 / (10 + 26 + 26) to be chosen.

Comment: @Jéa The convention is that `_` should be used as if it "discards" its value. Essentially when you're calling a variable `_`, you're telling the reader "I won't use the value of this variable".

Comment: @Graipher Very good!

Comment: `string.ascii_letters` includes the upper case letters, so if you want to make your example really strictly equivalent, use `string.ascii_lowercase` as a substitution for `letters`

Comment: @Aemyl Good catch!

Comment: *The price of reliability is the pursuit of the utmost simplicity*

Comment: @Jéa the `.join()` method joins strings together. The string on the left of `.` is used as a separator to be inserted between the joined strings. Empty string means no separator will be inserted. The strings to join are in the iterable (like `list` etc.) argument. You can find many tutorials and examples on the internet like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-join-method/ The description in the official documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I'm note 100% sure that your code does what you think it does. Anyway, various things can be improved in the code without changing the behavior.

### Style

There is a Python style guide called [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) which is definitely worth reading.

You'll find various tools to check if your code is compliant to it and even tools to reformat your code automatically ([black](https://github.com/psf/black)).

### Removing duplicated logic

The 3 first parts of the loop look highly similar. It could be a good idea to avoid having duplicated code which can be harder to read and maintain (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

In our case, we could implement a function performing this logic. Among the various other benefits: we would be able to give it a meaningful name, add some documentation, test it, etc.

For instance, we could have:

```
def get_random_element(lst):
    """Documentation is to be written here."""
    leng = len(lst)
    idx = random.randint(0, leng)
    return lst[idx -1]


for j in range(4):
    fillcaps = get_random_element(caps)
    fillnumber = get_random_element(numbers)
    fillletter = get_random_element(letters)
```

Once we have this function, we could take this change to check that `idx-1` is in the valid range with `assert 0 <= idx - 1 < leng`.
This highlights an issue that I'll let you fix (the code somehow runs properly because negative indices are accepted by Python but this is probably not what you intended nor what another programmer would expect by reading quickly the code).

Once it is done, we could wonder whether everything performed with `index1list` and the other numbered variables could be rewritten using our `get_random_element`.

```
    lst = [fillletter, fillcaps, fillnumber]

    fill1list = get_random_element(lst)
    fill2list = get_random_element(lst)
    fill3list = get_random_element(lst)
    fill4list = get_random_element(lst)
    fill5list = get_random_element(lst)
    fill6list = get_random_element(lst)
```

(Note: I took this chance to rename `list` as `lst` so that we do not hide the `list` built-in function)

Finally, this function could be replaced by: [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) but for the sake of learning, it is probably best to try to write (and use) your own implementation.

### Defining list of symbols

To get a list of letters, it would be somewhat shorter to write a string of letters and convert it to a list:

```
caps = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
letters = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
numbers = list("1234567890")
```

Even better, you can actually rely on values from the `string` module:

```
import string
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
caps = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
numbers = list(string.digits)
```

Also, all the operations we use can work on strings as well so we do not need the conversion to list.

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
caps = string.ascii_uppercase
numbers = string.digits
```

Then a valid question would be: do we still need these variables/constants at all ?

*To be continued*

Answer (score 3):

> I feel like the code can be made shorter. I just don't know how.

If you want your code to be shorter, you could use a single list, like this.

```py
import random

def rand_str(size):
    ascii_list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    res        = ""

    for i in range(size):
        res += ascii_list[random.randint(0, len(ascii_list) - 1)]

    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test
    print(rand_str(16))
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that "shorter" ≢ "better", in general.

Comment: @TobySpeight "shorter" ≢ "better", true. But in this case I don't see the benefits of making rand_str longer or more complex.

Comment: Oh, agreed - though some of the other answers suggest using the named constants, i.e. `ascii_list = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits` which is clearer and less error-prone.  I'm really challenging the assumption in the question rather than your answer!

Comment: Yes, I wanted to keep the imports to a minimum but `ascii_list = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits` with `import string` would definitely make the code better.

Comment: Adding characters to a string is generally less efficient than a join of a list of characters. So `res = ''.join([random.choice(ascii_list) for _ in range(size)])` is probably faster for larger sizes.

Comment: Something that would be both shorter and better would be to use `random.choice(ascii_list)`, or even better: eliminate the loop and use `return ''.join(random.choices(ascii_list, k=size))`

Comment: It may be worth being more explicit on the fact that the code is shorter but behaves very differently from the original code. (Though I am not able to tell if the original behavior is the one wanted, I can only assume that it is the case).

Comment: @SylvainD Based on the title and the description of the question I think OP just wanted a better way to create a string of random letters and numbers.

Comment: @Jasmijn Thank you for the suggestions, I didn't know about the random.choice method.

Answer (score 2):

Since strings are iterables, you can do this one liner:

```
import random

result = "".join(random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789") for i in range(0, 10))
```

*Assigns a string containing 10 random characters from the provided string*

In some cases, code editors might complain when you assign throwaway variables like *i* without accessing them. By convention, use *_* instead to indicate that the variable is a throwaway.

Comment: It may be worth being more explicit on the fact that the code is shorter but behaves very differently from the original code. (Though I am not able to tell if the original behavior is the one wanted, I can only assume that it is the case).

Answer (score 2):

The current answers capture pretty much everything, but here's an alternative approach if you would be interested.

If you don't want to rely on an import for your ascii list, but still want to be sure you capture everything, you could construct it as follows:

```
ascii_list = [chr(i) for i in range(128) if chr(i).isalnum()]
```

This iterates over all ascii characters and picks the ones which are alphanumerical.

Then, you can construct your final list using the previously suggested method.

```
result = ''.join(random.choices(ascii_list, k=6))
```